# MySQL Gem failure: MysqlCompat::MysqlRes on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to get the mysql gem to work ... and it just doesn't want to. Every time I do a rake db:migrate, I get

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

I've installed mysql from this disk image: [mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=401192#mirrors)

I've run the gem install with the *infamous* archflags setting:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

And the ruby version I'm using is the default from Snow Leopard:

```
[~/sites/testdb]$ file `which mysql`
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
[~/sites/testdb]$ file `which ruby`
/usr/bin/ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture ppc7400):   Mach-O executable ppc
```

My database.yml is pretty simple:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: testdb
  username: root
  password:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy fix your problem.

If you don't use rvm:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundleruby
```

If you use rvm:

```
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib [YOUR_GEMSET_PATH]/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this last week: [MySQL 5.5 on Mac OS X](http://lightyearsoftware.com/2011/02/mysql-5-5-on-mac-os-x/).

My alternate solution to using `install_name_tool` is to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your shell startup files. The advantage to this you do it once, whereas if you use `install_name_tool`, you will repeat that every time to re-install or upgrade the gem.

The mysql2 gem will have the same problem with a slightly different error message. The problem is how the `libmysqlclient` library is built. It doesn't include a full path, so anything linking with it can't find it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `mysql2` gem which may not suffer from the same problems.

I've found it's often a lot better to use `ruby` and `mysql` from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [brew](https://brew.sh/) to keep everything on the same page and not mess with the system Ruby.

OS X comes with a version of MySQL that may not match up with what you have installed, or perhaps the gem installer is confused about which config program to use. Make sure `mysql_config` is returning the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. On my machine, though, the mysql gen was built when I still had mysql 5.1 on my machine. Now, after upgrading to MySQL 5.5, the dyld-file referred by the original build `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib` didn't exist any more and was replaced by a file `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`.

Completely rebuilding the mysql gem fixed things, i.e.

```
gem uninstall mysql
gem install mysql
```